# Eclipse IDE is not able to launch in my system

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Whenever I launch the eclipse IDE this message will popup and eclipse will not open:

> An error has occurred. See the log file.

Log file data:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-12-25 20:50:34.318
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
```

Comment: The situation may depend on which Eclipse version that you have, as well was what Java version. See if [this information](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089060/) might help?

Comment: This often means you are using an older version of Eclipse with a newer version of Java. Old versions of Eclipse will not run with the newer versions of Java. So make sure you are using the current Eclipse (2019-12) and at least Java 8.